# ERROR: hyperledger/fabric:make gotools: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata"

Tags: docker, go, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

When make peer, it can't access build/docker/gotools/bin/protoc-gen-go, so I make gotools, but fail, here is the log:

```
mkdir -p build/bin
cd gotools && make install BINDIR=/root/gocode/bin
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/gocode/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gotools'
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/gocode/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gotools'
Building github.com/golang/lint/golint -> golint
package golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata" (https fetch: Get https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata?go-get=1: net/http: TLS handshake timeout)
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'gotool.golint' failed
```

How to solve this issue? Please help me, thank you!

Comment: It says: `(https fetch: Get https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata?go-get=1: net/http: TLS handshake timeout)` ... This seems to work fine for me, so check your internet connection (or maybe just try again, could be a temporary error on the server).

Comment: Thank you!  I tried many times, still unable to access 'https://go.googlesource.com/tools/'. Now I'm trying the docker method, though it seems very slow.

Comment: but it is strange that my computer actually can access or ping to this address

Answer (score 1):

Try to following the steps:

```
#mkdir -p gotools/build/gopath/src/golang.org/x/

#cd gotools/build/gopath/src/golang.org/x/

#git clone https://github.com/golang/tools.git

#cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/
```

Then make again

```
#make gotools
```